# Problem 1 from Herstein's book on Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that the product of two right cosets of $H$ in $G$ is again a right coset of $H$ in $G$, prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

**Proof:** Let $Ha$ and $Hb$ are two right cosets of $H$ in $G.$ By condition we know that $HaHb$ is again right coset. Since $a\in Ha, \ b\in Hb$ $\Rightarrow$ $ab\in HaHb$ and right cosets are disjoint then $HaHb=Hab$
Then  $HaHa^{-1}=H$ $\Rightarrow$ $aHa^{-1}\subset H$ and this inclusion is correct for any $a\in G$.

Thus, $H$ is normal in $G$.

**EDIT:** Why $aHa^{-1}\subset H$? If $z\in aHa^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=aha^{-1}$ for $h\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=eaha^{-1}\in HaHa^{-1}=H$ $\Rightarrow$ $z\in H$. Thus $aHa^{-1}\subset H$.

*Remark:* Please do not duplicate it and please take a look at this proof and assess is the way of my proof is correct?

Comment: It seems to correct.

Comment: I don't understandt this part which is not related to your proof.               
Right cosets are disjoint then $HaHb=Hab$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, What part of proof? Point out please,

Comment: This part: Right cosets are disjoint then $HaHb=Hab$. I  know this is true.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, If you that it's true why are you asking? :)

Comment: My one side is not convinced:)

Comment: Ok. I looked proof. Anyway, your proof seems so short and correct.

Comment: I think you still need to prove $H\subset aHa^{-1}$. (It's not difficult but needs done.)

Comment: ancientmathematician: $H=aHa^-1$ just a property of norma subgroup. It is enough to show that  for all $a\in G$, $aHa^{-1}\subset H$ for normality.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Done! You are right it should be done in order the proof to be complete!

Comment: You have still just done the inclusion one way. At this level you need to put in all the steps despite @1ENİGMA1's (true) assertion.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Yes I have shown that $H\subset aHa^{-1}$ for any $a\in G$. But the inverse inclusion is easy and is shown in my book (Herstein's book and I've decided to skip it). P.S. The definition of normal subgroup $H$ in $G$ in my book is the following: $gHg^{-1}\subset H$ for any $g\in G$.

Comment: If that's your definition, fine. I concede.